# Derivative of exponential of a sparse parametrized matrix with respect to the parameters

Tags: matrices, derivatives, numerical-methods, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

I have a Hermitian matrix of the type

$$H = H(c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n)$$

where $c_i$'s are some complex parameters. I need to find the derivatives

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial c_j}\text{exp}(H)$$

for each $c_j$. I don't think it will be of the form $\text{exp}(H)\frac{dH}{dc_j}$ because $H$ and $\frac{dH}{dc_j}$ won't necessarily commute. Does anyone have an analytical/numerical suggestion for this problem?

This looks promising: [Derivative of matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map) - but would be very complicated to implement numerically. Are there any other methods for this?

Edit: Will the fact that $H$ is a sparse matrix help?

Comment: Does it come with some overall scaling parameter? Like $e^{-\beta H}$ would be more common. Then when plugging in the formula you linked you can power count in $\beta$. So when $\beta$ is small, you only need very few terms of that series to get a numerically good answer.

Comment: Numerically, it might be easiest to diagonalize H and calculate the [derivatives of the eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann–Feynman_theorem)...

Comment: If I diagonalize H how do I keep track of the parameters in order to differentiate with respect to them?

Comment: Numerically perhaps I could do a H(c_j + h) - H(c_j) but then would both be diagonalizable together?